# Spring Security Kerberos - using Authentication from session to make Kerberized calls on behalf of user

Tags: spring-security, kerberos, kerberos-delegation, spring-security-kerberos

I'm trying to implement REST services over LDAP directory. Both have Kerberos-protected access. I already have working code (based on [Security Server Spnego and Form Auth Sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/reference/samples.html#samples-sec-server-spnego-form-auth) sample), which login user and store `autentication` object in users session. Then I make REST call to my app with sessionID and Spring Security pass it through - that's ok.
But now in REST controller I want to make an LDAP call *on behalf of logged user* using for example Spring's LdapTemplate class.
I have `KerberosUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instance from user session. From it how can I make `KerberosLdapContextSource` which is needed for LdapTemplate to make an LDAP calls?

Whether such an approach is correct and implementable at all?
If so, could you please suggest some sample code.

Comment: Why do you explicitly need the creds of the user? Does the user have more permission in the directory?

Comment: Rather the opposite case - the user may have fewer rights than the app/service. And in order  to not implement user authorization in the application and shift this responsibility to the directory itself.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Regular users never ever have write access to Active Directory. I'd never elevate a personal account to write to AD, only a specific, ACL'ed functional account. A user account can read the entire DIT. I don't see a problem here you cannot solve without the sytem keytab or the service keytab. Yet another problem, you cannot pool those connections.